# PHP posting json to server cause duplicate insert of data

Tags: php, json, api

I trying to post a JSON to server API endpoint using below codes, it cause duplicate entry inserted.

`$fileBinStr = $_POST['fileBinStr'];` This will need to post a huge digit of image base64 string. However, if I remove this row, it will insert only 1 entry.

**Question:** Is there anyway for me to prevent the duplicate entry insert or which part I had did it wrongly?

```
 $billNumber = $_POST['billNumber'];
 $billType = $_POST['billType'];
 $geoLocationX = $_POST['geoLocationX'];
 $geoLocationY = $_POST['geoLocationY'];
 $authToken = $_POST['authToken'];
 $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
 $fileBinStr = $_POST['fileBinStr'];
 $data = array(
    'command' => 'Uploadphoto',
    'billNumber' => $billNumber,
    'billType' => $billType,
    'geoLocationX' => $geoLocationX,
    'geoLocationY' => $geoLocationY,
    'fileName' => $fileName,
    'fileBinStr' => $fileBinStr,
    'authToken' => $authToken
    );
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    $data = base64_encode($data_json);
    $url ="{myendpoint}";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response1  = curl_exec($ch);

        $obj=json_decode($response1,true);
        foreach($obj as $key => $value){
         // decode the $value string
        $value = json_decode($value, true);
        $result = $obj['result'];
```

Comment: What is the code which insert the data? Can you show?

Comment: I'm corporate with the other side of people. So I don't have the insert data code, which mean possible is their side problem of insert data? But is strange when I remove the long digit of image string, the double entry issue solved, just I need to insert the image string.